# Como recuperar un valor en Arreglo o ArrayList en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

estoy realizando un arreglo o un arraylist, he hecho las dos pruebas pero no he podido recuperar el valor, esto es en VB.NET, paso dos fechas como parametro, a esta saco el numero de meses que contare y luego los asigno, hasta alli bien, luego lo quiero agregar el valor al mes que corresponde, este es el codigo:

```
Dim anCountMESES As Integer = 0
Dim anNumeroINI As Integer = Month(pdFchIngreso)
Dim anNumeroFIN As Integer = Month(pdFchPros)
Dim anMeses = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

For i = anNumeroINI To anNumeroFIN
            anCountMESES += 1
            'Agregar el numero del mes al arreglo de los meses
            anMeses.Add(i, anNumeroINI)
            '
            array.Add(anNumeroINI)

            anNumeroINI += 1
        Next

Select Case Month(pdFchPros)
            Case 1 ' Enero
                'Rango en meseses
                aoReturn.mnENE = 1
                aoReturn.mnFEB = 0
                aoReturn.mnMAR = 0
                aoReturn.mnABR = 0
                aoReturn.mnMAY = 0
                aoReturn.mnJUN = 0
                aoReturn.mnJUL = 0
                aoReturn.mnAGO = 8
                aoReturn.mnSEP = 9
                aoReturn.mnOCT = 10
                aoReturn.mnNOV = 11
                aoReturn.mnDIC = 12

                'Rango en años
                aoReturn.mnANIO01 = anANIOPROC - 1
                aoReturn.mnANIO02 = 0
                aoReturn.mnANIO03 = 0
                aoReturn.mnANIO04 = 0
                aoReturn.mnANIO05 = 0
                aoReturn.mnANIO06 = 0
                aoReturn.mnANIO07 = 0
                aoReturn.mnANIO08 = anANIOPROC - 1
                aoReturn.mnANIO09 = anANIOPROC - 1
                aoReturn.mnANIO10 = anANIOPROC - 1
                aoReturn.mnANIO11 = anANIOPROC - 1
                aoReturn.mnANIO12 = anANIOPROC - 1
end select
```

Espero su ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: Tu codigo es confuso.. que tratas de recuperar y de que arreglo?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta y lo que pretendes. ¿Dónde está definido array? Y el código que muestras ¿qué pertenece a una función? Por qué no la pones para ver los parámetros que le pasas. En qué sentencia fallida tratas de recuperar el valor?

Comment: ' Funcion Encontrar meses de Procesos del Colaborador' esta recibe dos parametros una fecha de fin de proceso de dd/MM/yyyy.otra fecha de Ingreso del Colaborador dd/MM/YYYY' de estas dos fechas obtener el numero de meses que a percibido ingresos que pueden ser de uno a seis meses en base a estos dos parametros obtengo el numero de meses, ejemplo un colaborador inicio en Marzo continua hasta Junio, tiene 4 meses' ya se el mes inicial,ahora se necesita recuperar esos 4 meses por el mes es decir, 3,4,5,6 y estos los quiero agregar a una clase que' tengo global o Publica,

Comment: Public Function mpxfindmesproceso(ByVal pdFchPros As Date, ByVal pdFchIngreso As Date) As clenominameses
'Variables que retonar el objeto al valor de las clase de estructura de meses
Dim aoReturn As clenominameses
Dim anANIOPROC As Integer = pdFchPros.Year
Dim anNumeroMeses As Integer()
Dim anMesPago As Integer = 4
Dim anCountMESES As Integer = 0
Dim anCountANIOS As Integer = 0
Parametros de fecha
Dim anNumeroINI As Integer = Month(pdFchIngreso)
Dim anNumeroFIN As Integer = Month(pdFchPros)

Comment: 'Calcular o sacar los meses del empleado a pagar
For i = anNumeroINI To anNumeroFIN
anCountMESES += 1
Agregar el numero del mes al arreglo de los meses
anMeses.Add(i, anNumeroINI)
array.Add(anNumeroINI)
anNumeroINI += 1
        Next
Select Case Month(pdFchPros)
Case 1 ' Enero
 'Rango en meseses
aoReturn.mnENE = 1
aoReturn.mnFEB = 0
aoReturn.mnMAR = 0
Return aoReturn
End Function

Comment: aoReturn.mnENE = array.IndexOf(0, 1)
aoReturn.mnFEB = array.IndexOf(1, 2)
aoReturn.mnMAR = array.IndexOf(2, 3)
aoReturn.mnABR = array.IndexOf(3, 4)
aoReturn.mnMAY = array.IndexOf(4, 5)
aoReturn.mnJUN = array.IndexOf(5, 6)
aoReturn.mnJUL = 0
aoReturn.mnAGO = 0
aoReturn.mnSEP = 0
aoReturn.mnOCT = 0
aoReturn.mnNOV = 0
aoReturn.mnDIC = 0

Comment: En serio te abacenhoi

Comment: Case 6 'Junio
------ aqui me da error, alli quiero asignarle el numero del mes
     aoReturn.mnENE = array.IndexOf(0, 1)
        aoReturn.mnFEB = array.IndexOf(1, 2)
        aoReturn.mnMAR = array.IndexOf(2, 3)
        aoReturn.mnABR = array.IndexOf(3, 4)
       aoReturn.mnMAY = array.IndexOf(4, 5)
       aoReturn.mnJUN = array.IndexOf(5, 6)
      aoReturn.mnJUL = 0
       aoReturn.mnAGO = 0
      aoReturn.mnSEP = 0
      aoReturn.mnOCT = 0
      aoReturn.mnNOV = 0
      aoReturn.mnDIC = 0
end select

Comment: Me entendieron lo que necesito hacer don Antonio y gbianchi.

Comment: Cambie el codigo, trabaje con un Dictionary, pero me da error, al tratar de recuperar el valor que necesito, presento el codigo a ver si me dan me una luz:
Dim aoReturn As clenominameses
Dim anMeses = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)
For i = anNumeroINI To anNumeroFIN
'Agregar el numero del mes al arreglo de los meses
anMeses.Add(i, anNumeroINI)
next
Aqui quiero recuperar el numero del mes que viene en el diccionario:
aoReturn.mnENE = IIf(anMeses.ContainsKey(aoReturn.mnENE), anMeses.Item(aoReturn.mnENE), 0)

Espero sus comentarios a lo que necesito.